# How to run transformation in parallel spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to read text.gz file, repartition it and do some transformation, however when I see the DAG the stag1 is reading the data and doing the transformation on only 1 task and it is taking time because of that.
[image]

Most of the time is spend on stage 1.
[image]

I don't understand why the processing is done on only one task how can I split it after I read the data.
Code for stag1

```
df1 =spark.read.text("text-04-14.log.gz")
df1 = df1.repartition(20)
text_to_json_udf = udf(text_to_json, ArrayType(StringType()))
df1 = df1.select(text_to_json_udf(df1.value).alias("arr_cols"))
df1 = df1.dropna()
cols = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'k7', 'k8', 'k9']
df1 = df1.select([df1.arr_cols[i].alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(cols)])
```

Answer (score 2):

A .gz file is not splittable, hence Spark reads that whole file on 1 core - slow. After that Stage, repartitioning can be applied to increase throughput of processing.

Comment: that's correct. depending on the use case, it might also be worth to re-compress in another format, e.g. bzip2, lz4, lzo, snappy etc. - or just leave it uncompressed. Depending on size of data and decompression time of course

Comment: @UninformedUser  sure, that is also an option

Comment: @thebluephantom I know the .gz file is not splittable hence I am repartitioning the data after read. But the udf functions after that are also running on the single core. I am not sure why this is happening. what should I do to run it in parallel.

Comment: Then you need to pose the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Because .gz, the file extension for gzip files (GNU zip, an open source file compression program).

- And the compression file ,it should decompress before splitting.
- When you cache the decompresses data in memory, or persist it on the disk, you can repartition it in your customer partitioner or default.

And more, why the stage1 only has  only 1 task is because of the spark job stage dependencies; The stage1's source code below. In other words, the code below is stage1;So the stage2 should have 20 task in parallel;

```
df1 =spark.read.text("text-04-14.log.gz")
df1 = df1.repartition(20)
```

so the stage1 is the shuffle map stage, it only read the data in one task if the input data is low than 128MB.

Comment: I didn't get your second point.
If you can refer to my code above I have repartitioned it after reading how can I improve it to run the UDF function in parallel?

Comment: I have add some additional information to clarify the question.

Comment: In stag1 if only the reading of data and repartition was done it was ok, but in my case the udf functions are also running on 1core and not in parallel of 20.